# Spring 3 Hibernate Spring MVC Arch Type

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

Does anyone know of a good archytype for Spring Web MVC with Hibernate ? I have been searching and have not been able to find any ?

Kind Regards,

Muhammad Mateen

Answer (score 1):

You could use appFuse: http://static.appfuse.org/archetypes.html

However, I would recommend spring ROO.  Spring ROO doesn't provide archetypes, but does provide a similar skeleton setup via spring roo commands.

Comment: Could you please show some example. I am only slightly familiar with ROO. You help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think its best you follow the tutorial: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html
Also, I recommend you install spring STS as it comes with spring ROO and other things to make setup/dev easier.